# Adding menu to library project

Tags: android

I have create a library project as well as 2 main project one is paid and the other is free in android google store. Now I have an activity in library project which is common to both the other projects.

I want to add a menu item on that activity that is only visible to the paid app and is not shown in the  free app. Also I want to create an activity in the paid app which is called by the library project activity.
How can I call this activity from library project as the library project do not know about this activity presence?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the wrong architecture.  Libraries aren't supposed to depend on anything in the application that's using them.  You'll have to figure out how the paid app can start that activity.  Without knowing more I can't say how that might work, but possibly the library can call a callback method when it's done doing something.

Library:

```
public void doSomething(Callback callback){
    // Do some stuff
    if(callback != null){
        callback.done();
    }
}
```

Free app:

```
library.doSomething(null);
```

Paid app:

```
library.doSomething(new Callback(){
    // start activity
});
```

Comment: I have already a free app in the android store. I wanted to have 2 version of the app(paid and free). After reading a lot on internet I had 2 options, in app purchase and creating a common library. Since in app purchase was a little complicated to implement I decided to go with the second approach. Moved all my code to library and then created 2 projects in eclipse paid and free and referred to the common library. This is the what I am following

Comment: "Moved all my code to library and then created 2 projects in eclipse paid and free and referred to the common library."  That's good, but you're also referring to the paid/free stuff from the common library, which is what's causing you problems.